# R:how to use random forests to predict binary outcome when features are super-sparse?

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, random-forest, text-mining

Consider this

```
outcome <- c(1,0,0,1,1)
string <- c('I love pasta','hello world', '1+1 = 2','pasta madness', 'pizza madness')

df = df=data.frame(outcome,string)


> df
  outcome        string
1       1  I love pasta
2       0   hello world
3       0       1+1 = 2
4       1 pasta madness
5       1 pizza madness
```

Here I would like to use **random forests** to understand which words in the sentences contained in the `string` variable are **strong predictors** of the `outcome` variable.

Someone suggested to use the `randomForest` package

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)    
outcome <- c(1,0,0,1,1)
    string <- c('I love pasta','hello world', '1+1 = 2','pasta madness', 'pizza madness')
df <- data.frame(outcome=factor(outcome,levels=c(0,1)),string, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

inp <- df %>% mutate(string=strsplit(string,split=" ")) %>% unnest(string)
library(randomForest)
mm <- model.matrix(outcome~string,inp)
rf <- randomForest(mm, inp$outcome, importance=TRUE)
imp <- importance(rf)
```

Problem is: my original dataset is much larger. Think of the `string` column as a short english sentence of 5/6 words. The full dataset has 800k observations. Here, randomForest fails because of obvious memory issues.

What would be an alternative algorithm for my classification purpose?

Many thanks!

Comment: As you've discovered, randomForest is notoriously poor for sparse data. Some other options include linear SVMs (inner products of binary indicators are cheap) or more advanced methods like neural networks for NLP tasks.

Comment: thanks @Sycorax. Someone mentioned boosting. What do you think?

Comment: I'm not an expert in boosting, but I don't see how that would help.

Comment: Sounds like you're using your bag of words to try to classify tweet sentiment?

Comment: i am not using twitter data at all, although its similar. think of the outcome as one if the sentence is popular.

Comment: In other words, my data is already labeled with 0 - 1 outcomes, and I want to understand which words explain the variation in outcome

Answer (score 1):

Try to convert your sparse data into an sparse matrix via one-hot encoding and them use random forest within Caret package...I'm not quire sure if random forest package can work with sparse matrix.,.. use other algorithm such as GBM or xgboost if random forest is giving your poor fit.

Comment: thanks! can you code that you using the example above?

Comment: It is very simple. You need to install the library (Matrix): https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Matrix/index.html and make sure all your variables are numeric and factor. Then:  sparse_matrix <- sparse.model.matrix(outcome~-1, data = df)   ------------- this will dummy code all your sparse categorical variables.